# Call method from main method?

Tags: java

Im trying to make 2 methods. The main method has the user input, and the other method called ShowNum should output the...output. Heres my original code with one main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int days;
int num;

System.out.print("Enter number of days: ");
days = keyboard.nextInt();   

System.out.print("Enter number for first day: ");   
num = keyboard.nextInt();

int half = days/2;
int newnum = num + 2;     

      System.out.println("Day \t Number"); 

          for (int current_day = 1; current_day <= half; current_day++){        
              newnum = newnum - 2;                                            
              System.out.println(current_day + "\t" + (newnum + 2));
          }
          for (int current_day = half + 1; current_day <= days; current_day++){ 
              newnum++;                                                        
              System.out.println(current_day + "\t" + (newnum + 2)); 
          }
```

Ive tried this:

```
public static void DisplayNum(){          
   int half = days / 2; 
   int newnum = num + 2;                                              

   System.out.println("Day \t Num"); 

       for (int current_day = 1; current_day <= (days/2); current_day++){        
            newnum = newnum - 2;                                            
            System.out.println(current_day + "\t" + (num + 2)); 
              }
       for (int current_day = (days/2) + 1; current_day <= days; current_day++){ 
                  newnum++;                                                        
                  System.out.println(current_day + "\t" + (num + 2)); 
              }
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int days;                                          
        int num;                                      

          System.out.print("Enter number of days in the period of time: ");   
            days = keyboard.nextInt();                                        

          System.out.print("Enter number for first day: ");               
            num = keyboard.nextInt();                                        



           DisplayNum();
```

Its a mess of errors because the variables aren't all defined in both methods but I don't know how to make them defined without just making it in one method. This is basically what my professor said to do yet I'm very confused. I'd appreciate help or any other advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is related DisplayNum(); in your code?

Comment: oh sorry typo I fixed it. Its the name of the other method.

Comment: check my answer and if it's helps you let me know.

Comment: your methods are inside your class, which you can define global variables to and use it for all the methods

Comment: You should really read some beginner tutorial which covers method parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add arguments into your function `DisplayNum()` like this `DisplayNum(int days, int num)` and then call this method into your main method
`DisplayNum(days,num)`.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! That just about fixed it. Do you mind explaining why you put the int stuff in the ()? How does that define them?

Comment: @vee you need to pass days and num int variable into DisplayNum method because you are using these variables into your main method as local variables and these variables has not accessible outside from main method. so one method is to pass these variables into function arguments and If you don't want to pass arguments to your DisplayNum function so you need to use your variables as Global variables.

Comment: Ah~ Yes I get it now. Thanks again.

Comment: @vee:
I recommend [_The Java Tutorials_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).
You should probably start somewhere in
"[Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html)",
maybe the
"[Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/)" lesson.
Method parameters and return values are specifically covered in
"[Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)"
and
"[Returning a Value from a Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)".

Answer (score 0):

pass the variables that you want to use from main method as parameter of the DisplayNum method

```
    public static void DisplayNum(int days,int num){          
   int half = days / 2; 
   int newnum = num + 2;                                              

   System.out.println("Day \t Num"); 

       for (int current_day = 1; current_day <= (days/2); current_day++){        
            newnum = newnum - 2;                                            
            System.out.println(current_day + "\t" + (num + 2)); 
              }
       for (int current_day = (days/2) + 1; current_day <= days; current_day++){ 
                  newnum++;                                                        
                  System.out.println(current_day + "\t" + (num + 2)); 
              }
    }
```

Then in main method pass in the values for parameter

```
public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int days;                                          
    int temp;                                          //variable for starting temperature

      System.out.print("Enter number of days in the period of time: ");   
        days = keyboard.nextInt();                                        

      System.out.print("Enter number for first day: ");               
        num = keyboard.nextInt();                                        



       DisplayNum(days,temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `days` and `temp` values ad arguments to your `DisplayNum` method. 
You should define `public static void DisplayNum(int days int temp)` and call `DisplayNum(days, temp)` from your `main` method.